# Skewed Random Numbers with Defined Intervals

Tags: r

Is there a way to generate skewed random variable imposing some defined intervals? For example, a FICO score in the range of 500 to 800. Here's my attempt so far:

```
set.seed(12345)

n=100
x <- c(1:n)
mu <- 600 + 100 * sin( x * pi / 24 )
e <- 100*rnorm( length(mu) )
y <- mu + e
plot( x, y )
lines( x, mu, col="red" )
legend('topleft',c('mu'),col=c('red'),lty=c(1,2),bty="n",cex=0.78)
```

However, this code generates scores beyond the required intervals [500,800].

Thanks

Comment: in what sense your generated variable `y` is skewed? It seems to have pretty symmetric histogram. Do you want positively or negatively skewed?

Comment: Either negative or positive would do, just need to understand how to generate such variables. Mine is pretty symmetric, agreed.

Comment: For anyone trying to respond, please note I'm not looking to generate skewed normal variate such as the one generated by:   curve(dnorm(x,m=650,sd=50),from=400,to=800,main="Normal distribution")

Comment: Just take rbeta and linearly remap [0, 1] to [500, 800].